# Rewriting route closure 301 redirects into controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have implemented 301 redirect in Laravel 5.5+ web.php for some pdf files, e.g.

```
Route::get(
    'old-url.pdf', function () {
    return Redirect::to('new-url.pdf', 301);
});
```

It works great on a dev environment.

However, when deployed on the production site, due to caching (caching doesn't allow serialization of closures), I get errors such as

```
LogicException: Noticed exception 'LogicException' with message 'Unable to prepare route [old-url.pdf] for serialization. Uses Closure.' in /XXX/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:880
```

I am looking for an example on how to re-write the redirect above using controllers (or any other recommended method)

Comment: `new-url.pdf` ?? what is this `.pdf`  in URL

Comment: the pdf part isn't very relevant to the question: just redirecting some old urls to new ones.

Comment: so remove it and use `new-url` only

Answer (score 1):

We have a `RedirectController` built into the framework to allow you to avoid this issue:

```
Route::redirect('old-url.pdf', 'new-url.pdf', 301); // 301 by default
```

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Routing - Redirect Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#redirect-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this ([read my comment for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833908/rewriting-route-closure-301-redirects-into-controllers-in-laravel/51834040#comment90621763_51833908))

```
Route::get('/old-url', function () {
    return Redirect::to('new-url');
});
```

Comment: That doesn't help me: it is still a closure. And the files I am redirecting are pdfs, that is why I gave a pdf in the original example.

Comment: I've modified my original post to include more information